# Google drive api for codeigniter to view image gallery

Tags: php, google-drive-api, codeigniter-3

Is there any api for codeigniter or raw php, which will show images from google drive folder to my website with light box?

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=1eTvcSyMfB-L4Z2aYodg8xdfdH2d2OPoDvR5u#grid" style="width:100%; height:800px; border:0"></iframe>
```

I'm using this code to bring the folder to my website, but i need lightbox to show images.

I'm looking for a soltion similar to this one    https://preview.codecanyon.net/item/useyourdrive-google-drive-plugin-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/6219776?_ga=2.213734807.2030918436.1596026069-1754475108.1595612291

Comment: Are you looking for PHP code that displays images in a lightbox gallery? If so may I recommend this website: http://tangledindesign.com/css-lightbox-made-practical-with-php/. You should be able to adapt this code to point to the folder you brought to your website.

Comment: No, I am not looking for a lightbox only. I am looking for a complete solution actually. to be more specific, i'm looking for an API